# Invalid date format for validation flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form, the date picker is supposed to validate and check whether the end date is later than the start date. But my coding got error which says

> Invalid date format
> 09/01/2023`

Here is my validation code:

```
TextEditingController _sDate = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _eDate = TextEditingController();
String? endDateValidator(value) {
DateTime eDate = DateTime.parse(_eDate.text);
DateTime sDate = DateTime.parse(_sDate.text);
eDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(eDate);
if (_sDate != null && _eDate == null) {
     return "select Both data";
}
if (_eDate == null) return "select end date";
if (_eDate != null) {
    if(eDate.isBefore(sDate))
         return "End date must be after start date";
    }
    return null;}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to share your complete code? What is `_sDate`?

Comment: @MendelG sorry my bad, it was a textediting controller

Answer (score 0):

Your date format is not regular(yyyy-MM-dd) format, you need to use custom format to format it, so instead of this:

```
DateTime eDate = DateTime.parse(_eDate.text);
DateTime sDate = DateTime.parse(_sDate.text);
eDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(eDate);
```

You can use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install) package and do this::

```
DateTime eDate = DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(_eDate.text);
```

also in line four of your code, `format(eDate)` return you a `string`, you can't pass it to `eDate`, because it is `DateTime`. Also you don't need this line at all.

Comment: I have actually tried this method before, there was another error which was `The following FormatException was thrown while handling a gesture:
Trying to read dd from  at position 0` @eamirho3ein

Comment: can you show me the result of `print("_sDate = ${_sDate.text}");` and `print("_eDate = ${_eDate.text}");` ? @MaisarahMohamed

Comment: it shows `_sDate = 09/01/2023` and `_eDate = 10/01/2023`. However I cant make it validate my textformfield properly

Comment: I can't understand why you get this exception, could you update your question with my answer, maybe you miss something @MaisarahMohamed

Comment: its okay, i just found out another solution to my problem. Thank you for trying to help me appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods of formatting dates if we are working in Flutter:

1.- Add the intl package  (https://pub.dev/packages/intl) and you can access to this functions:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat.yMMMEd().format(now);
print(formattedDate);

Output:
Tue, Jan 25, 2022
```

2.- Using Custom Pattern

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
formattedDate = DateFormat('EEEE, MMM d, yyyy').format(now);
print(formattedDate);
Output:
Tuesday, Jan 25, 2022
```

For more information:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

I hope it was useful for you.